# Does Android Rotation Vector Sensor use the magnetometer readings?

Tags: android, android-sensors, gyroscope, digital-compass

As known, the so-called "Rotation Vector Sensor" is a virtual sensor.

I know for sure that it takes the readings from accelerometer and gyroscope for computation.

However, now I wish to know whether the magnetometer readings are also take into the calculation of the Rotation Vector Sensor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relation constitutes to

> The rotation vector sensor reports the orientation of the device relative to the East-North-Up coordinates frame.

The underlying physical sensors are Accelerometer, Magnetometer, and Gyroscope, while the latter is used as the main orientation change input.
Furthermore source.android.com says

> This sensor also uses accelerometer and magnetometer input to make up for gyroscope drift, and it cannot be implemented using only the accelerometer and magnetometer.

In contrary the `Game rotation vector` explicitly only uses the Accelerometer and Gyroscope. I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36664018/how-does-the-rotation-vector-sensor-generates-information) on how the data is acutally fused, yet to be answered.
The link also directs to this table
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `rotation vector` is a combination of the `accelerometer`, the `magnetometer`, and sometimes the `gyroscope` to determine the three-dimensional angle along which the Android device lays with respect to the Earth frame coordinates.